# How many Intervals are in a period?

Tags: mysql, datediff

Given a table with two dates and a date interval (i.e. `6 WEEKS`), how can I count how many times this interval fits in this date interval?

In my PHP script I'm using a simple for loop, but I'd like to add this in a MySQL query.

A simple calculation would be to count the number of days between the dates and then assume a month has 30 days and a year has 365 days, but that's not always true.

How can I calculate with `datediff` and a date interval string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understood you correctly, you need the [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function.

The first parameter is the unit of the interval. The result is how many units are between the two dates.